UITextView Leaves a Gap Below Keyboard When Dismissing on Swipe in Live Chat Interface
I'm developing an iOS app in Swift with a global live chat interface. The interface includes a UITableView for messages, a UITextView for typing messages, and a send button. Everything is set up using Auto Layout.
The Issue:
When the keyboard appears, the UITextView moves up correctly. However, when the keyboard is dismissed by swiping down, a gap is left between the UITextView and the bottom of the screen. The UITextView does not reattach to the bottom of the screen properly.
What I've Tried:
Observing UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification and UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification to adjust the bottom constraint of the UITextView.
Using .interactive keyboard dismissal for the UITableView.
Adding a pan gesture recognizer to detect swipes on the view to dismiss the keyboard.
Despite these, the gap persists. I want the UITextView to stay attached to the keyboard and properly reattach to the bottom when the keyboard is dismissed.
Relevant Code:
[![@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?\[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey\] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.messageInputBarBottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardHeight + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.scrollToBottom()
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.messageInputBarBottomConstraint?.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}][1]][1]

Full ViewController:
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class ChatViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

    private var messages: [(text: String, senderID: String)] = []
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let messageInputBar = UIView()
    private let messageTextView = UITextView()
    private let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium)

    // Constraint reference for the bottom of the messageInputBar
    private var messageInputBarBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    private var messageTextViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the background color
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#02272D")

        // Set up the title
        title = "Global Chat"

        // Add the close button
        let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .close, target: self, action: #selector(closeButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        setupUI()
        setupLoadingIndicator()
        listenForMessages()

        // Add observers for keyboard notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        // Initially disable the send button
        updateSendButtonState()

        // Add swipe down gesture recognizer to dismiss the keyboard
        let swipeDownGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        swipeDownGesture.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownGesture)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc private func closeButtonTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        isModalInPresentation = false // Allow interactive dismissal
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        // Set up message input bar
        messageInputBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageInputBar.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        view.addSubview(messageInputBar)

        // Set up text view
        messageTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        messageTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        messageTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 18
        messageTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        messageTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        messageTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 10, bottom: 8, right: 10)
        messageTextView.delegate = self
        messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageInputBar.addSubview(messageTextView)

        // Set up send button
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .medium)
        let upArrowImage = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up", withConfiguration: config)
        sendButton.setImage(upArrowImage, for: .normal)
        sendButton.tintColor = .white
        sendButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        sendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        messageInputBar.addSubview(sendButton)

        // Set up table view
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        // Constraints for the message input bar
        messageInputBarBottomConstraint = messageInputBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageInputBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            messageInputBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            messageInputBarBottomConstraint!,
            messageInputBar.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50)
        ])

        // Constraints for the message text view
        messageTextViewHeightConstraint = messageTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            messageTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.topAnchor, constant: 7),
            messageTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -7),
            messageTextViewHeightConstraint!,
            messageTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])

        // Constraints for the send button
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        // Constraints for the table view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageInputBar.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func setupLoadingIndicator() {
        loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loadingIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            loadingIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc func sendButtonTapped() {
        guard let text = messageTextView.text, !text.isEmpty else { return }
        sendMessage(text: text)
        messageTextView.text = ""
        messageTextViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 36
        updateSendButtonState()
    }

    private func sendMessage(text: String) {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            print("User not authenticated")
            return
        }

        let message = [
            "text": text,
            "senderID": user.uid,
            "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()
        ] as [String : Any]

        ref.child("messages").childByAutoId().setValue(message) { error, _ in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error sending message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Message sent successfully")
                self.scrollToBottom()
            }
        }
    }

    private func listenForMessages() {
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        ref.child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
            if let messageData = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
               let text = messageData["text"] as? String,
               let senderID = messageData["senderID"] as? String {

                self.messages.append((text: text, senderID: senderID))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.scrollToBottom()
            }
            self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "messageCell")
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.text
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = message.senderID
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard Handling

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.messageInputBarBottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardHeight + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.scrollToBottom()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.messageInputBarBottomConstraint?.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc private func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    private func scrollToBottom() {
        if messages.count > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITextViewDelegate

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let maxHeight: CGFloat = 100
        let size = CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        messageTextViewHeightConstraint?.constant = min(estimatedSize.height, maxHeight)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = estimatedSize.height >= maxHeight

        updateSendButtonState()
    }

    private func updateSendButtonState() {
        let isTextEmpty = messageTextView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
        sendButton.isEnabled = !isTextEmpty
        sendButton.backgroundColor = isTextEmpty ? UIColor.gray : UIColor.systemBlue
    }
}

